# Running a SELECT in a PL/pgSQL block

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am newbie to PostgreSQL and I have to use inline queries in SSRS report to fetch data from PostgreSQL DB.

The scenario is: based on selected value of the report parameter I need to get output from different tables. Please see the below sample inline query.

```
    DO
    $do$

    BEGIN
    IF ($1 = 'Monthly') THEN

    SELECT *
    FROM table1;

    ELSE 

    SELECT *
    FROM table2;

    END IF;

    END
    $do$
```

The above query is giving error,

> **ERROR**: query has no destination for result data
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
>   Context: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 6 at SQL statement

Please note that I cannot use Stored procedures or Functions to retrieve the required data and I have to use inline queries only.

Can some one let me know of how to solve above error?

Comment: The result of a select needs to go _somewhere_ - so you need to put the result into a variable. And your code is reduced so much that it doesn't make sense any more: `if (1 > 0)` will always be true and the second statement will never be executed. You can replace the whole block with `select * from table1`

Comment: Please find below the updated query,                                                   DO
$do$

BEGIN
IF ($1 = 'Monthly') THEN
 
   SELECT *
  FROM table1;

ELSE 
 
   SELECT *
  FROM table2;

END IF;

END
$do$

Comment: You cannot pass arguments into an anonymous code block, nor can you return a result from it. So what you propose will never work.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your reply. So is there is any work around to achieve the required behavior? This would have been a simple query in SQL Server, however I find it disappointing that similar stuff is not supported by Postgresql.

Comment: Well, every DBMS is different. You will always find things in one DBMS that can't be ported directly to another. I can name many things that SQL Server can't do but are _very_ easy in Postgres. And besides: you wouldn't be able to do something like that in Oracle or DB2 either.

Answer (score 9):

Your examples has two issues - DO statement (anonymous block) doesn't support

1. parameters
2. returning result.

PostgreSQL doesn't support techniques used in T-SQL or MS-SQL called unbound queries. Every query has to have specified target. You can use a function instead (`table1` and `table2` should to have same structure):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(frequency)
RETURNS SETOF table1 AS $$
BEGIN
  IF $1 = 'Monthly' THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM table1;
  ELSE
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM table2;
  END IF;
  RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM foo('Monthly');
```

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks for your inputs. The above solution will not work in my scenario as we cannot create any functions/stored procedures into Postgresql DB. We have to use inline queries only to fetch the data. Please let me know if there is any other way of achieving the same?

Comment: @VinayakZirmirkar - then you have to do this decision in application, or with UNION like Gary described. There is not any other way.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the tables have the same column structure you can use a union to do both options in a single query.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE $1 = 'Monthly'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE NOT ($1 = 'Monthly')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a temporary table to get the result outside, but not to pass the parameter:

```
DO
$$
BEGIN
IF <> THEN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo AS
SELECT *FROM ...
 ELSE

 ....
 END IF;
 END
 $$
 SELECT * FROM FOO;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you create a function that accepts a 'select' query text and returns `SETOF RECORD`, then you can execute directly in the sql window:

```
with c_sql as (
-- >>> --- your any query
select STRING_AGG('select ''"' || t.table_schema || '"."' || t.table_name || '"'' tab, count(*) cnt from "' || t.table_schema || '"."' || t.table_name || '"', ' union all ')
|| ' order by 2 desc' v_sql
from information_schema.tables t
where t.table_schema like 'tiger'
-- <<< ---
)
select ex.* from c_sql
LEFT JOIN lateral ( select * from execsql(c_sql.v_sql) as ss(tab text, cnt int8) ) ex on true
```

this is **execsql** function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.execsql(
text)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN 
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE $1 ; 
END 
$BODY$;
```

> note that you should convert the result of the **execsql** function to a
> specific record structure that matches your 'select' query.

---

PS:
*By the way, I do not understand why no one recommended such a simple way of executing almost any request. this is a very useful way to quickly form a query and execute it without creating separate functions that clog the database.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursors:

```
BEGIN; -- open a transaction to extend the scope visibility of the cursor

DO $$
DECLARE
  _cursor cursor FOR select * from my_table;
BEGIN
  OPEN _cursor;
END
$$;

FETCH ALL FROM _cursor;

ABORT;
```